# Remote Postgresql Query - Permission denied for table xxxx

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Struggling to remotly query a postgres database.

I've populated the /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf / postgresql.conf  with the correct information.

I know I can query remotely as its working from within PyCharm.

But EVERY time I try this command I'm getting an error

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="******", database="******", user="******", password="********")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(f"""select id, login_count, orders from "user" where account = '{account}' """)
```

ERROR:

```
permission denied for table user
```

Postgresql log:

```
2021-09-08 23:03:52.353 UTC [11354] colemanbros@colemans ERROR:  permission denied for table user
2021-09-08 23:03:52.353 UTC [11354] colemanbros@colemans STATEMENT:  select * from "user"
```

The login credentials for both pycharm and psycopg2 are the same. And both are being run from my local machine.

Psycopg2 on jupyter

Pycharm is connecting to the database with jdbc

Can anyone offer some insight into why this might be?

Comment: SSL maybe? It's a strange one

Comment: Actually, you mention jdbc, which 'psycopg2` definitely is not. Maybe there are some connector parameters that aren't being passed

Comment: It must be that, I will continue down that vein for now.

Comment: Add `%u` and `%d` to `log_line_prefix` and see if it is the same user in the same database.

Comment: .... or you can simply `SELECT current_user` from both environments to see if users are the same. Are you sure the hosts, ports and database names match? It's not a rare mistake when you have multiple instances of the same DB. :)

Comment: Totally all my own doing - wrong username. What a doofus!!!